# SAPUI5 XmlView Show Data from Aggregation Binding Child

Tags: odata, sapui5

I need to get all the `ContactEmployees` contacts of each `BusinessPartners` client, in a Table List. Contacts are loaded but I can not show fields

My request `https://***/BusinessPartners?$select=ContactEmployees&$skip=0&$top=20`

My JSON Result from request "Only Selected ContactEmployees"

```
{
   "@odata.context" : "https://**********$metadata#BusinessPartners",
   "value" : [
      {
         "ContactEmployees" : [
            {
               "CardCode" : "C000002",
               "Name" : "Jose Duran",
               "Position" : null,
               "Address" : null,
               "Phone1" : null,
               "Phone2" : null
            },
            {
               "CardCode" : "C000003",
               "Name" : "Leo Manuel",
               "Position" : null,
               "Address" : null,
               "Phone1" : null,
               "Phone2" : null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "ContactEmployees" : [
            {
               "CardCode" : "C000010",
               "Name" : "MILDRED MEJIA",
               "Position" : null,
               "Address" : null,
               "Phone1" : null,
               "Phone2" : null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "ContactEmployees" : []
      },
      {
         "ContactEmployees" : []
      }
   ],
   "@odata.nextLink" : "BusinessPartners?$select=ContactEmployees&$skip=23&$top=5"
}
```

My Table View

```
            <Table id="idPartnerTable"
                    growing="true"
                    growingScrollToLoad="true"
                    inset="false"
                    items="{
                        path: '/BusinessPartners',
                        parameters:{
                        $select:'ContactEmployees,CardCode'
                        },
                        sorter: {
                            path: 'CardCode'
                        }
                    }">
                    <columns>
                        <Column id="carcode">
                            <Text text="ID" />
                        </Column>
                        <Column id="nombre" >
                            <Text text="Name" />
                        </Column>

                    </columns>
                    <items>
                        <ColumnListItem
                            type="Navigation"
                            press="onPress">                            
                            <cells>
                                <Text text="{ContactEmployees/CardCode} "/>
                                <Text text="{ContactEmployees/Name} "/>
                            </cells>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </items>
            </Table>
```

CONSOLE ERRORS

> Failed to drill-down into ('BUSINESSPARTNERS
>   CODES')/ContactEmployees/Name, invalid segment: Name -
>   /******/BusinessPartners?$select=ContactEmployees,CardCode&$orderby=CardCode sap.ui.model.odata.v4.lib._Cache

If I change `{ContactEmployees/Name}` to `{ContactEmployees/0/Name}` they are shown but only 1 single contact, and I need to bring them all

Answer (score 0):

Use the expand option in order to get the ContactEmployees of each BusinessPartners. 
try this :

```
 <Table id="idPartnerTable"
                    growing="true"
                    growingScrollToLoad="true"
                    inset="false"
                    items="{
                        path: '/BusinessPartners',
                        parameters:{
                        expand:'ContactEmployees'
                        },
                        sorter: {
                            path: 'CardCode'
                        }
                    }">
```

here is plunker it could help you : http://plnkr.co/edit/Q6KqSRk4kk0V81AdCrvQ?p=preview

Comment: tried to expand, but "ContactEmployees" is a property of BusinessPartners.
<Property Name = "ContactEmployees" Type = "Collection (SAPB1.ContactEmployee)" />
, then I throw the following  console error when I added expand... 
with start index 0 and length 20 - Error: Cannot expand invalid navigation property 'ContactEmployees' for entity type 'BusinessPartner'